# Can a function be considered continuous if its discontinuity is filled by a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If I have the following function:

$$f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),x\neq0$$
$$f(x)=0,x=0$$

Can we find the derivative of the function at $x=0$?

I know that the condition for differentiability at a point is that a function should be continuous at that point and $f'(a)$ should exist, as in the limit:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
should exist. Now, my question here is can we consider this limit to exist at $x=0$? I mean since $f(x)$ at $x=0$ isn't actually a part of $x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, will the point $\left(0,f(0)\right)$ take the properties of the rest of the curve (properties such as slope)? And hence, does $f'(0)$ exist?

Comment: $f$ is defined properly for all $x$. You can evaluate the limit using algebra of limits. What's the issue?

Comment: Your function is perfectly defined on whole $\mathbb{R}$ including $0$. The fact that this definition is piecewise is not a problem, as long as this is dealt with correctly, which you seem to do. And yes, $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: Continuity has nothing to do with how you write a function.

Comment: For example, we can define $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ or define it piecewise:  $$g(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\geq 0\\-x&x<0\end{cases}$$ they are the same function.

Comment: Your function is continuous and everywhere-differentiable with $f'(0) = 0$, as the limit in your question exists (though the derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$). You could see the discontinuity of the derivative at $x=0$ as showing that the derivative there belongs to $f(x)$, and not to the function $x^2 \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$, the rest of the curve, but such a notion is intuitive only, and doesn't have any rigorous meaning. (Interesting note, $x^2 \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ is $C^\omega$ (in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$), but $f$ is only $C^0$.)

Comment: (+1) The moral, as pointed out by earlier comments, is not to conflate _functions_ and _algebraic/closed formulas_. In calculus we focus on formulas because they're a simple, explicit way to define functions. A function is not merely a formula, however. At bottom, what matters is that we've assigned a _unique value_ to each point of the domain.